# How to integrate credit card payment into my android app

Tags: android

I have an POS app. Now i want to integrate credit card payment feature into my app. Where can i get start? I really don't have any clue about this. Please give me a tip!

Thanks.

Comment: Multiple ways to do: 1- you can implemenet your own web service to keep CC and proceed(not ethic) 2- You can simply use 3rd party MasterPay or Paypal which is easy and their tutorial on everywhere. 3- you can mix some stuff lile using stripe will allow you ethically keep cc info in known servers and you can only deal with some token, then you can try AndroidPay to complete or direct android pay. pick one and search for tutorial or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://www.ccavenue.com/) link! It is an external library to integrate payment gateway